# Versioning resources files from Java webapp

Tags: java, html, css, caching, browser

I have a problem with a personal application.

Each time I upload a new version of It, my users have problems with css, js and images resources.

I would like to do something that change the URL of those resources at every new version (the project includes maven)  **but still cache informations** to gain page loading time.

But I don't know if I can change the URL of call and don't change the path of the resource in the app. Does any solution exists such as filter or url rewriter? (Like `/{version}/res/css/style.css`) I can't find anything about It...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a query parameter ?v={version} to your static resource requests.

[RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) states that

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component, serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority

Thus the parameter should be taken into account when caching.

Most browsers will cache it. Perhaps some proxy servers will not, these days most will. The assumptions that it does not happen are based on 8 year old findings, see [Steve Sounders's blog](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)

You could rev the filename itself or the path. That are the other options.

Comment: I've seen somewhere that url with parameters aren't cached... I don't know if that's a great solution because of that :/

Comment: yes, that used to be the case. I added some more background